# How to convert UTC time into Unix time stamp in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, timestamp

I get UTC time as a string.Now i want to convert this string UTC time into unix time stamp. Please suggest how can I convert UTC time to unix time stamp.

Comment: Here is the (http://stackoverflow.com/a/37856922/3675182)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift convert unix time to date and time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26849237/swift-convert-unix-time-to-date-and-time)

Answer (score 0):

Convert that string to `NSDate` then use that date with `.timeIntervalSince1970`, it will produce timestamp in `Double`

Answer (score 0):

Use this to convert unix time

```
let timeInterval  = 1415639000 (Your time interval)
let unixTime = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: timeInterval)
```

Answer (score 0):

i used it like that

```
let timeInterval = datePicker.date.timeIntervalSince1970
let unixTime = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: timeInterval)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
extension String {

  //MARK:UTCStringToDate
  var utcStringToUnix:NSTimeInterval {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
     dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
    let utcDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(self)
  let unixTime =   utcDate?.timeIntervalSince1970

       return unixTime!
  }
}
```

use this extension.. to use just  :  `let unix =  utcString.utcStringToUnix`