# How to convert this UNIX epoch date in milliseconds to local date/time?

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

I am getting something strange date/time from server.

[image]

How to convert **"notification_date": 1500461137000,**
to local time format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift convert unix time to date and time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26849237/swift-convert-unix-time-to-date-and-time)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a UNIX epoch date in milliseconds. You can convert it with `timeIntervalSince1970` after dividing it by 1000.

```
let localDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: notificationDate / 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do an extension on Double and convert from your notification date.

```
 Double(notificationDate).convertEpochTime()
 ...
 extension Double {
    func convertEpochTime() -> String{
       let readableDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: self / 1000.0)

       let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
       dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
       dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, MMM d"

       return dateFormatter.string(from: readableDate)
   }
}
```