# How do i convert a timestamp string into a date?

Tags: javascript

I have the following string "1576354589.222591". How can I covert it into a date?

I tried `new Date(1576354589.222591).toLocaleString()` but that does not work. It gives me 1/8/1970

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift convert unix time to date and time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26849237/swift-convert-unix-time-to-date-and-time)

Comment: sorry I meant javascript not swift

Comment: @Reinstate Monica Read the comment right above yours.  He first used the swift tag.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript

Comment: convert from string use parseInt new Date(parseInt('1576354589.222591')*1000).toLocaleString();

Answer (score 2):

`Date` expects the date in milliseconds, not seconds, so multiply the value by 1000:

```
new Date(1576354589.222591*1000).toLocaleString()
```

yields:

```
"12/14/2019, 12:16:29 PM"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Timestamp** is in milliseconds so need to multiply by **1000** to convernt into seconds. By below snippet you can find **date+time** or **only date**
or **only time**.

```js
var Date_and_Time = new Date(1576354589.222591*1000).toLocaleString();
var Only_Date = new Date(1576354589.222591*1000).toLocaleDateString();
var Only_Time = new Date(1576354589.222591*1000).toLocaleTimeString();

console.log('Date and Time: '+Date_and_Time);
console.log('Only Date: '+Only_Date);
console.log('Only Time: '+Only_Time);
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using

`new Date(1576354589.222591*1000).toLocaleString()`

and another alternative approach can be done by using moment.js

In case if you want to use here is the documentation link https://momentjs.com/guides/

Check out the code below in snippet.

```js
console.log(moment(1576354589.222591).format("DD MMM YYYY hh:mm a"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```